# Change font in a textbox object to small caps - PowerPoint 2013

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I can't find anywhere on the internet how to change the font of a textbox to small caps. I've tried many variations of the failing line but can't get it to work. Can someone help?

```
With objPPTTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = "Title"
    .Font.Size = 14
    .Font2.Smallcaps = msoTrue  ---Fails here!---
    .Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer thanks to this [website](http://skp.mvps.org/2007/ppt006.htm)

```
objPPTTextbox.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Smallcaps = msoTrue
```