# VBA for using Font Format "Small Caps" in PowerPoint, MS

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on a presentation (Power Point) for my job and they decided to change the format of the Presentation Agenda and now the text it appears on it uses "Small Caps". We use a Macro in PP for creating the Agenda, but I've been searching a couple of hours and I haven't found anything about using the font effect "Small Caps" in VBA. I actually am starting to learn macros but they asked me this anyways, so I'd appreciate very much you're help. The most I could do was the following:

```
        titleBox.Text = titles(i)

        With titleBox.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 12
        End With
        titleBox.Characters(2, 100).Font.Size = 10
        titleBox.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
```

titles(i) is defined elsewhere and includes the names of the titles that will appear in the presentation agenda, all in uppercase. I'm trying to emulate "Small Caps" manually as I've tried "Font.SmallCaps = True" and it doesn't work (as it does in Word). The problem with what I'm doing is that when typing:

titleBox.Characters(2, 100).Font.Size = 10

I decrease the font size of all the letters after the first one, but I'd like to decrease the font size of all the letters after the first word of EVERY word in a sentence.

This is what I referred as "manually", but if you know another way to implement "Small Caps" in Power Point that would be very helpful.

I hope I explained myself. Thanks,

HvZ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change font in a textbox object to small caps - PowerPoint 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217519/change-font-in-a-textbox-object-to-small-caps-powerpoint-2013)